# Is a batsman out when any of his things slip away and hit the stumps?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is a batsman out if his helmet, bat or any of his equipment slip away from him and hit the stumps?
It always confuses me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from Spinner, noting that "any part of his clothing or equipment" can cause a dismissal by Hit Wicket, is correct. I would just like to add a few examples of things that have actually fallen onto the batsman's wicket, causing the batsman to be out Hit Wicket.

- A **dropped bat**. [This happened](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf_OyKOOa7U) to Kumar Sangakkara in a match against India in 2009.
- A **helmet**. This has [happened to Adam Parore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hox3YvJLSXs) after being hit by a short ball from Brett Lee, and to Kevin Pietersen, [similarly dismissed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTeSRp16xbk) by Dwayne Bravo
- A **cap**. [A gust of wind](http://www.espncricinfo.com/wisdencricketer/content/story/231414.html) blew the cap of Warwickshire's MJK Smith at Edgebaston onto his own wicket.
- A **glove**. [This happened](http://www.espncricinfo.com/wisdencricketer/content/story/231414.html) to Alf Revill in 1953

I searched for "Hit Wicket shoe" and "Hit wicket Toupee", but couldn't find any reports, but they would of course also be covered by "any part of his clothing or equipment".

Comment: what if? http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/11908/what-if-an-opposing-player-uses-part-of-the-batsmans-clothing-to-put-down-the-w

Comment: Regular TMS listeners will of course be wondering what the law is for a detached beard.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it would be out hit wicket under [Law 35.1 (a)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-35-hit-wicket/). [Law 28.1](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-28-the-wicket-is-down/) indicates that the wicket can be put down by the ball, the bat, any part of the bat becoming detached, the striker's person, or "any part of his clothing or equipment becoming detached."

Comment: What if a batsman puts his helmet behind the stumps, while a spinner is bowling and an opposing player uses it to knock off the bails?

Comment: @msh210 http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/11908/what-if-an-opposing-player-uses-part-of-the-batsmans-clothing-to-put-down-the-w