# What if an opposing player uses part of the Batsman's clothing to put down the wicket?

Tags: rules, cricket

Following on [from](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/11902/is-a-batsman-out-when-any-of-his-thing-slips-away-and-hit-the-stumps/11903),

Lets suppose that a batsman is facing an over of spin, he/she has removed thier helmet and placed it behind the stumps for safe keeping.

What if, while the ball is in flight, an opposing player uses the helmet to put down the wicket? Would the batsman be out? Assuming not, which laws preclude this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batting Team is not allowed to keep their helmets behind the wicket or any part of the ground. If the don't want the helmet they should send it back to the dressing room